# Is there any way to run a vector in checkluhn package?

Tags: r, luhn

I try to run the following code:

```
library(checkLuhn)
library(gsheet)
data<-gsheet2tbl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/145Wowgp6NXmcj-IqqKfZ-2B2aKwAOzZ1VuCjxAq7WeM/edit?usp=sharing")


df <- data.frame(Card  = character(), 
                     Active = character(),
                     issuer =character())

for (i in 1: nrow(data))
{
  card <- data[i,2]  
  active <- checkLuhn(card)
  issuer <- issuer(card)
  df = rbind(df, data.frame(Card = card, Active = active, Issuer =issuer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
```

But it is showing the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(Card = card, Active = active, Issuer = issuer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with `issuer` which returns logical `FALSE` if there is none or else return a two column `tibble`.  We could check the output type and make changes

```
library(purrr)
library(checkLuhn)
library(gsheet)
map_dfr(data$Number, ~  {
  active <- checkLuhn(.x)
  issuer <- issuer(.x)['issuer']
  if(is.logical(issuer)) issuer <- tibble(issuer= NA_character_)
   tibble(card = .x, active, issuer)
  })
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 3
   card                active issuer                   
   <chr>               <lgl>  <chr>                    
 1 378 2822 4631 0005  TRUE   American Express         
 2 371 4496 3539 8431  TRUE   American Express         
 3 378 7344 9367 1000  TRUE   American Express         
 4 5610 5910 8101 8250 TRUE   Bankcard                 
 5 5610 5910 8101 8250 TRUE   Maestro                  
 6 30 5693 0902 5904   TRUE   Diners Club Carte Blanche
 7 6011 1111 1111 1110 FALSE  <NA>                     
 8 6011 0009 9013 9420 FALSE  <NA>                     
 9 3530 1113 3330 0000 TRUE   JCB                      
10 3566 0020 2036 0500 FALSE  <NA>                     
11 5555 5555 5555 4440 FALSE  <NA>                     
12 5105 1051 0510 5100 TRUE   MasterCard               
13 4111 1111 1111 1110 FALSE  <NA>                     
14 4012 8888 8888 1880 FALSE  <NA>                     
15 4 2222 2222 2222    TRUE   Visa                     
16 760 0924 4561       FALSE  <NA>                     
17 5019 7170 1010 3740 FALSE  <NA>                     
18 6331 1019 9999 0010 FALSE  <NA>
```

---

Or using the OP's code

```
df <- data.frame(Card  = character(), 
                     Active = character(),
                     Issuer =character())
for (i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  card <- data[[2]][i]  
  active <- checkLuhn(card)
  issuer <- issuer(card); 
  if(NROW(issuer) == 0 |is.logical(issuer))  {
     issuer <-  NA_character_
    }else {
    issuer <- issuer$issuer    }
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(Card = card, 
     Active = active, Issuer =issuer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
```

-output

```
 df
                  Card Active                    Issuer
1   378 2822 4631 0005   TRUE          American Express
2   371 4496 3539 8431   TRUE          American Express
3   378 7344 9367 1000   TRUE          American Express
4  5610 5910 8101 8250   TRUE                  Bankcard
5  5610 5910 8101 8250   TRUE                   Maestro
6    30 5693 0902 5904   TRUE Diners Club Carte Blanche
7    38 5200 0002 3237   TRUE                      <NA>
8  6011 1111 1111 1110  FALSE                      <NA>
9  6011 0009 9013 9420  FALSE                      <NA>
10 3530 1113 3330 0000   TRUE                       JCB
11 3566 0020 2036 0500  FALSE                      <NA>
12 5555 5555 5555 4440  FALSE                      <NA>
13 5105 1051 0510 5100   TRUE                MasterCard
14 4111 1111 1111 1110  FALSE                      <NA>
15 4012 8888 8888 1880  FALSE                      <NA>
16    4 2222 2222 2222   TRUE                      Visa
17       760 0924 4561  FALSE                      <NA>
18 5019 7170 1010 3740  FALSE                      <NA>
19 6331 1019 9999 0010  FALSE                      <NA>
```